# Is there a way for me to specify the date function in MySQLWorkBench so that I won’t get an error message?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-date-functions

I tried to create a table, this is how I set it up:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_tab
(  
  empno             NUMeric(10),  
  name              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
  job               VARCHAR(50),  
  manager           NUMeric(10),  
  hiredate          DATE,  
  salary            NUMeric(10,2),  
  commission        NUMeric(10,2),  
  deptno            NUMeric(5),  
  CONSTRAINT pk_emp_tab PRIMARY KEY (empno),  
  CONSTRAINT fk_emp_tab_deptno FOREIGN KEY (deptno) 
  REFERENCES dept_tab(deptno)  
);
```

this is how I insert values:

```
INSERT INTO emp_tab
 VALUES(7004, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7002,  
 date('87-7-13') - 85,  
 3000, null, 70
);


INSERT INTO emp_tab 
VALUES(7007, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7003,  
 date('87-7-13') - 51,  
 1100, null, 40  
);
```

Oddly enough, I did not get an error message for the first inserted value but I got the error message for the second inserted value that says "Incorrect date value: '19870662' for column 'hiredate' at row 1) but after I removed - 51, it worked. However, it will give me incorrect date so I am wondering if there is any chance I can keep - 51 without getting errors?

Comment: So what should this values 85 and 51 are? Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Days ...

Comment: 85 and 51 are days, so I want to see what date will it fall on if I subtract 85 and 51 days, I was able to do that for 85 but not for 51 in MySQL so I'm not sure why, it works for me in PostgreSQL though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a well formatted date and DATE_SUB()

```
DATE_SUB(DATE('1987-07-13'), INTERVAL 85 DAY)
```